# How to remove specific word if they exist before a word in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which can look like

```
"word1 AND word2 AND word3 AND word4"
"word1 OR word3 AND word4"
"word1 word3"
```

I want to remove `word3` from string whenever it appears. For that i am using below code

```
regex = re.compile(re.escape('word3'), re.IGNORECASE)
keywords = regex.sub('', keywords)
```

I also want to remove any occurrence of `AND` or `OR` words if they appear before `word3`. Unable to figure out how to do it.

Output  i need is

```
"word1 AND word2 AND word4"
"word1 AND word4"
"word1"
```

There can be corner cases where `word3` is the first word in string. In that case the first AND/OR after if it exists should be removed

```
"word3 AND word4 or word1"
```

should become

```
"word4 or word1"
```

Comment: Note that unless you are handling those strings with any precedence rules apart from naive left-to-right, you will mess things up if you do this. Typically `AND` has greater precedence than `OR`; so `word1 AND word2 OR word3 AND word4` is executed as `(word1 AND word2) OR (word3 AND word4)`; if you remove `OR word3`, you get `word1 AND word2 AND word4`, a _very_ different expression.

Comment: I don't see any way to really do this with regex.  This issue is that a `word3` terms could be first, middle, or last, and in each of those cases, we might have to remove an `AND|OR` separator either before _or_ after the occurrence.  In general, you might need a parser here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closest I could get to anything resembling a working answer:

```
keywords = "word3 AND word3 OR word2 AND word1 AND word3 OR word4 AND word3"
keywords = re.sub(r'(?:(?:and|or) )?word3\s*', '', keywords, flags=re.I)
keywords = re.sub(r'^\s*(?:and|or)\s*', '', keywords, flags=re.I)
print(keywords)

word2 AND word1 AND word4
```

### Demo

First, we do a replacement similar to the other answers to remove a `word3` term.  In this case, I look for a possible preceding `AND|OR` term to also remove.  However, there is an edge case, e.g.

```
word3 AND word2 OR word1
```

Here we would end up with just this:

```
AND word2 OR word1
```

So, I make a *second* call to `re.sub` to remove a possible leading separator which might still be there.

There is still a problem with this answer.  In my sample input:

```
word3 AND word3 OR word2 AND word1 AND word3 OR word4 AND word3
```

Removing all `word3` terms *without* right away removing the separators leaves this:

```
word2 AND word1 AND OR word4
```

In other words, it is not clear *which* separator we should choose here, `AND` versus `OR`, to separate the `word1` and `word4` terms.

Comment: You are removing trailing separator but I want to remove the preceding one

Comment: @Pooja Answer updated.  Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're right about possible ambiguity, but you can cover both cases in one substitution with a pattern such as `( ?AND | ?OR )? ?word3\b(?(1)|(?: AND| OR)? ?)` (demo at https://regex101.com/r/P5LhUg/1/)

Comment: @jaytea Thanks for the comment, but I'm throwing in my hat for this question for now :-) ... too many edits already

Answer (score 3):

Put an optional group which can contain `' AND'` or `' OR'` before the escaped input:

```
keywords = "word1 AND word2 AND word3 AND word4"
regex = re.compile('(?:and |or )?' + re.escape('word3') + ' ?', re.IGNORECASE)
keywords = regex.sub('', keywords)
print(keywords)
```

Output:

```
word1 AND word2 AND word4
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work on input `word1 word2 word3`, because you have made the `and|or` separator mandatory.

Comment: and/or is not mandatory with that edit, but it still wouldn't work on `word1 word2 word3` because you made the trailing space mandatory...

Comment: Oops, thanks guys, fixed. Was trying to figure out a way to use `(?i)` and `(?-i)` for just the escaped input, but it doesn't seem to work with Python

Answer (score 3):

```
\s*(?:AND|OR)?\s*word3
```

Explanation:

- `\s*` at the start removes leading whitespace.
- `(?:AND|OR)?` matches `AND` or `OR` if they exist
- `\s*` allows whitespace before `word3`

And you should replace it with `""`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7ZN0NE/1)

Comment: What if "word3" is the first? Wouldn't you want to remove the whitespace to the right of it?

Comment: You should give Python code here if possible, and also show that your solution covers all edge cases.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Edited.

Comment: No wait, now it doesn't work properly if "word3" is first or last or both.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `replace` functionality.

```
s = "word1 AND word2 AND word3 AND word4"
s.replace(" AND word3", "").replace(" OR word3","").replace(" word3","")
'word1 AND word2 AND word4'
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to use regex with multiple matches. Please go through the below documentation

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch05s02.html

```
keywords = "word1 AND word2 AND word3 AND word4" +"word1 OR word3 AND word4"+"word1 word3"
re.sub(r'\s*word3(?: (?:and|or))?', '', keywords)
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around it. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @hellow Yes I missed it to give links :-) Updated as mentioned.